# LIBGDX Asset manager load true type font

Tags: java, android, fonts, libgdx

We are trying to load a true type font with the asset manager in a libgdx project. We followed striclty the [wiki entry](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets) . However, we get the exception

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load dependencies of asset: basicfont.ttf
```

with the following code

```
 // First, let's define the params and then load our smaller font
    FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter parameter = new FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter();
    parameter.fontFileName = "basicfont.ttf";
    parameter.fontParameters.size = 10;
    game.manager.load("font.ttf", BitmapFont.class, parameter);
    game.manager.finishLoading();
```

We already loaded the font without the asset manager. 
Moreover, we also read [this link](http://www.codingchronicles.com/libgdx/using-assetmanager-to-store-your-bitmap-fonts-in-libgdx) and followed the instruction, which did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String path="basicfont.ttf";     //can be inside nested folder
String fileName = "font.ttf" ;   // it can be any name with extension, will use to load and retrieve
```

Load in this way :

```
manager=new AssetManager();
FileHandleResolver resolver = new InternalFileHandleResolver();
manager.setLoader(FreeTypeFontGenerator.class, new FreeTypeFontGeneratorLoader(resolver));
manager.setLoader(BitmapFont.class, ".ttf", new FreetypeFontLoader(resolver));

FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter parms = new FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter();
parms.fontFileName = path;    // path of .ttf file where that exist 
parms.fontParameters.size = 10;
manager.load(fileName, BitmapFont.class, parms);   // fileName with extension, sameName will use to get from manager

manager.finishLoading();  //or use update() inside render() method
```

> Android file-system is case sensitive.

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

```
parameter.fontFileName = "basicfont.ttf";
game.manager.load("font.ttf", BitmapFont.class, parameter);
```

I think you should use the same name for font in the `load` method

```
game.manager.load("basicfont.ttf", BitmapFont.class, parameter);
```

Comment: According to [this link](http://www.codingchronicles.com/libgdx/using-assetmanager-to-store-your-bitmap-fonts-in-libgdx) the naming does not matter. Never the less, we also tried to use the same name for both, which did not solve the problem.

Comment: Correct, my mistake, however you should post some more of the logcat/stacktrace. There should be a “caused by” somewhere there which provides more info.